# java printstream image file

Tags: java, sockets

Is a `printstream` appropriate for sending image files through a socket? I'm currently doing a homework assignment where I have to write a web proxy from scratch using basic sockets.

When I configure firefox to use my proxy everything works fine except images don't download. If I go to an image file directly firefox comes back with the error: `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors`

Here is my code for sending the response from the server back to the client (firefox):

```
        BufferedReader serverResponse =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webServer.getInputStream()));
        String responseLine;
        while((responseLine = serverResponse.readLine()) != null)
        {
            serverOutput.println(responseLine);
        }
```

In the code above `serverOutput` is a `PrintStream` object. I am wondering if somehow the `PrintStream` is corrupting the data?

Comment: The `PrintStream` is a bad choice not because of character issues but because its `print()` methods swallow exceptions. It isn't appopriate to use `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` over a network, as you need to know about exceptions on the connection immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is never appropriate to treat bytes as text unless you know they are text.

Specifically, the InputStreamReader will try to decode your image (which can be treated as a byte array) to a String. Then your PrintStream will try to encode the String back to a byte array.

There is no guarantee that this will produce the original byte array. You might even get an exception, depending on what encoding Java decides to use, if some of the image bytes aren't valid encoded characters.

Comment: So both the `InputStreamReader` and the `PrintStream` were a bad choice?

Comment: @Deekor Yes. Although you couldn't use just one - you'd have to use both or neither in this case. (Or `OutputStreamWriter` instead of `PrintStream` which has exactly the same problem)

Comment: Is there any built in option in java for passing bytes along? or do all the readers and writers decode / encode them to text?

Comment: @Deekor `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s are for raw bytes. `Reader`s and `Writer`s are for text. (Which is why it's weird that you're converting your bytes to text and back)